# In which of these examples is conversion necessary?

Tags: c++

Here are three examples, where I get a number from a function with some general non-double type (could be some sort of int, some sort of size_t, etc), and need to store that in a double.

My question is, is the code fine as is in all three examples, or do I need to do some conversion?

```
double x = getNotDouble(); //Set x = some number.

//Set x equal to division between two non-doubles:
double x = getNotDouble() / getAnotherNotDouble(); 

//Take non-double in constructor
class myClass
{
    double x
    myClass(someType notDoublex) : x(NotDoublex)
};
```

Comment: Integer arithmetic is done using only integers. Take for example `1 / 2`, the result will be `0` even if assigning the result to a floating point variable.

Comment: depends on what you want. In some rare cases even assigning the result of a integer division to a double can be fine

Comment: Most everything you could want to know about this can be found here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion

Comment: Depends on what you call "necessary".   First example:   a conversion occurs implicitly.    Second example, it is necessary to explicitly convert the return value of at least one of the function to `double`, otherwise the division is integer division, and the integral result of division then converted (implicitly) to `double`.     If the constructor of `myClass` is passed an `int`, that will be implicitly converted to `double`, unless `myClass` has another constructor with argument of integral type.

Comment: These examples don't compile. Post real code.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, a conversion is used whenever you assign a value of one type to a variable of another type. In this respect, a conversion is needed in all three cases, since all three cases assign a non-`double` value to a `double` variable.

However, needing a conversion is not the same as needing to *specify* a conversion. Some conversions are provided automagically by the compiler. When this happens, you do not need to specify a conversion unless the automatic conversion is not the one you wanted. So whether or not a conversion needs to be specified depends on what you want to achieve.

Each of your three cases is correct in certain situations, but not necessarily in all situations. At the same time, each of your three cases could be enhanced with an explicit conversion, which would at least serve as a reminder to future programmers (including you!) that the conversion is intentional. This could be particularly useful when there are integers and division involved, since an explicit conversion could confirm that the intent is to convert to `double` *after* the integer division (dropping the fractional part).

In the end, what you need to do depends upon what you want to accomplish. One program's feature is another program's bug, simply because the programs seek to accomplish different goals.

---

Note that I have taken the following statement at face value:

> I get a number from a function [...] and need to store that in a double.

For the second example, the value being stored in a double is `getNotDouble() / getAnotherNotDouble()`. To make this fit the statement, I needed to interpret "function" in the mathematical sense, not the programming sense. That is, the division is the "function" producing the value to store in a double. Otherwise I would have *two* numbers from *two* C++ functions, and that is inconsistent with "a number from a function". So I read the question as asking whether or not a conversion is needed after the division.

If the intent was to ask if a conversion is needed before the division, the answer still depends upon what you want to accomplish. The behavior of division depends on its operands, not on what is done with the result. So if the operands are integers, then integer division is performed, and the result is an integer even if that resulting integer is then assigned to a floating point variable. Sometimes this is desired. Often not.

If you are storing the result of the division in a `double` because you want to store the fractional part of the quotient, then you would need to make sure at least one of the operands is a floating point value before the division is performed. (There are floating point types other than `double`, so "not double" is not enough to know if an explicit conversion is needed.) However, this is really a separate topic than what this question is nominally about since this is about the division operator, while the question is nominally about storing values.

Answer (score 0):

Your first and third example result in no loss of data, so I assume they're fine.

Your second example is where some loss of data takes place (integer division means the result is rounded down), which you could potentially:

```
double x = static_cast<double>(getNotDouble()) / getAnotherNotDouble();
```

One of the values has to be a double in order for the return value to also be a double.